# Rails: The Law of Demeter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, object-oriented, design

I am reading a book called Rails AntiPatterns and they talk about using delegation to to avoid breaking the Law of Demeter. Here is their prime example:

They believe that calling something like this in the controller is bad (and I agree)

```
@street = @invoice.customer.address.street
```

Their proposed solution is to do the following:

```
class Customer

    has_one :address
    belongs_to :invoice

    def street
        address.street
    end
end

class Invoice

    has_one :customer

    def customer_street
        customer.street
    end
end

@street = @invoice.customer_street
```

They are stating that since you only use one dot, you are not breaking the Law of Demeter here. I think this is incorrect, because you are still going through customer to go through address to get the invoice's street. I primarily got this idea from a blog post I read:

http://www.dan-manges.com/blog/37

In the blog post the prime example is

```
class Wallet
  attr_accessor :cash
end
class Customer
  has_one :wallet

  # attribute delegation
  def cash
    @wallet.cash
  end
end

class Paperboy
  def collect_money(customer, due_amount)
    if customer.cash < due_ammount
      raise InsufficientFundsError
    else
      customer.cash -= due_amount
      @collected_amount += due_amount
    end
  end
end
```

The blog post states that although there is only one dot `customer.cash` instead of `customer.wallet.cash`, this code still violates the Law of Demeter.

> Now in the Paperboy collect_money method, we don't have two dots, we
>   just have one in "customer.cash". Has this delegation solved our
>   problem? Not at all. If we look at the behavior, a paperboy is still
>   reaching directly into a customer's wallet to get cash out.

EDIT

I completely understand and agree that this is still a violation and I need to create a method in `Wallet` called withdraw that handles the payment for me and that I should call that method inside the `Customer` class. What I don't get is that according to this process, my first example still violates the Law of Demeter because `Invoice` is still reaching directly into `Customer` to get the street.

Can somebody help me clear the confusion. I have been searching for the past 2 days trying to let this topic sink in, but it is still confusing.